# Align email center in Outlook.com

Tags: html, email, outlook

I want to center my email in Outlook.com.
It works fine in every mail application, but not on Outlook.com

How can I fix this?

Code:

```
<table class="table-bestelling-content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#ffffff">
    <tr class="header" style="max-width: 600px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%;" >
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="email-heading head">
                        <h1>ORDERBEVESTIGING</h1>
                        <p>Hi {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerFirstname()}},</p> 
                        <p>Bedankt voor je bestelling!</p>
                        <p>Je bestelling heeft ordernummer {{var order.increment_id}}.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, do not style rows, you're asking for trouble.
I would stay away from margin:auto and just use align's on cells.
You have width="100%;" which will break because of the semicolon.

Change the second tables width to 600 (or whatever you need it to be) and then add align="center" to the cell housing that. 
Adding the align to the first cell makes all 600 wide tables inside of that inherit this alignment and will make your entire email centered.

Use this:

```
<table class="table-bestelling-content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#ffffff">
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" >
            <tr>
                <td align="center" class="email-heading head">
                    <h1>ORDERBEVESTIGING</h1>
                    <p>Hi {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerFirstname()}},</p> 
                    <p>Bedankt voor je bestelling!</p>
                    <p>Je bestelling heeft ordernummer {{var order.increment_id}}.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I want to center my email in Outlook.com. It works fine in every mail application, but not on Outlook.com

How can I fix this?

Code:

```
<table class="table-bestelling-content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#ffffff">
    <tr class="header" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" >
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="email-heading head">
                        <h1>ORDERBEVESTIGING</h1>
                        <p>Hi {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerFirstname()}},</p> 
                        <p>Bedankt voor je bestelling!</p>
                        <p>Je bestelling heeft ordernummer {{var order.increment_id}}.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi David, it does not work. And also it breaks down the responsive mail. Is there an other way?

Comment: Please post your CSS.  If you are sending emails you shouldn't be using classes anyways.  You need to decorate each tag with style=""

Comment: @DavidP he may be using a css inliner when he's done, or for instance mailchimp will automatically do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td width="600">
         Put all your emails tables/content here
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It does not work, but this is just the heading of the mail. Do I need to add align="center" to all <td> tags to make it work?

Comment: I tried your new code, but that does also not work. And we use a responsive template for mail, looks like this code will also break down the responsive template I guess?

Comment: @Jelle it might help if you post all of your code on a jsfiddle, or similar. Dont edit your posted code, just simply add the link to jsfiddle.